# Mapped Drive of windows is not accessible via 3rd party software named IGC of OpenText

Tags: windows, mapped-drive, opentext

I am trying to solve the problem of long path which is greater than 260 characters. I am using a 3rd party product namely IGC(Informative Graphics Corporation) of OpenText. For the solution, I am using mapped drive of windows so that my long path becomes a short path(less than 260 characters) and hence I would be able to overcome the limitation of IGC software. IGC is a blackbox for me. I just provide some jobs to it along with some parameters and IGC takes those arguments and produces the output in a designated directory. I am succesfully able to create mapped drive but don't know why IGC is not able to interpret the mapped drive and it gives the error "CDL 23, cannot load file provided at the Z:\input\somefile.pdf" However I am able to access it via windows explorer or google browser. Please provide a solution as to why IGC does not understand mapped drives or any other workarounds possible for this solution?

Comment: better use symbolic link or mount point instead mapped drive here

Comment: mapped drive is not resolved properly by the 3rd party software that I am using and the symbolic link does not really help as it gets resolved to full length path before getting processed. Moreover, we cannot create symbolic links with path of type \\ipv4Address\D$\somePath.

Comment: symbolic link or mount point is resolved by file system - so here no problem with path length. if you use network path - this is another question. are your program run in the same logon session ? may be it run elevated ?

Comment: Actually we are having cluster-node setup where the data can reside on a NAS. Hence I require the network path and when I create symbolic link with the command in windows cmd : mklink /j "D:\IGC1" \\10.2.1.109\D$\someLongFolderName\ with the "Elevated Command Prompt". Got the following error : "Local volumes are required to complete the operation.". Hence NAS cannot be given.

Comment: remove `j` option - try `mklink /d "D:\IGC1" \\10.2.1.109\D$\someLongFolderName` - this must work for symbolic link, but not for mount points

Comment: so i test - with `/j` really got *Local volumes are required to complete the operation.* error, but without this option *symbolic link created for...* and worked as well. but i guess that your program, which you say not work with mapped drive - run elevated - so in another logon session, where this drive not exist

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @RbMm. I was able to generate a network symbolic link but the third party software is failing and not able to resolve the symbolic link generated. So its more of an internal issue to that application, which is a black box for me as I submit jobs to IGC in the form of job files with various params and it produces output at a designated locaiton.

Comment: *but the third party software is failing and not able to resolve the symbolic link generated* - no. user mode software not resolve symbolic link - this is done auto by system. are say you can open this symlink in explorer ? reread my comments. i guess that your software run in **different logon session**. say it run **elevated**. the network share is per logon session. only this reason can explain. really your soft simply try open `D:\IGC1` folder as is. it not care are this symlink, are this link to mapped drive. but guess logon session wrong

Comment: Thanks a lot @RbMm . I got the solution I was looking for.